# bin packing with volume and weight and different bins

Tags: algorithm

In our company, we regularly import merchandises over the sea.

When we make an order, we have to distribute them into containers.
We basically can choose between three types of containers,
and our goal is of course to distribute the items so that we use the minimum number of container (and if possible the smallest container as they are cheaper).
We have two physical constraints:
- we cannot exceed the container maximum weight 
- we cannot exceed the container maximum volume

We have the volume and weight of each item.

Actually, we do the distribution manually, but it would be great if there was some kind of algorithm that could help make a distribution proposition for us.

So I found the bin-packing algorithm, but it often treats only the weight, or the volume, but not both at the same time.

My question is: is there an existing algorithm for our problem (and if so what's its name and how would you use it), or is it something that remains to be created?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I came across such issue few days ago, If I were you I would use the Genetic Algorithm to improve the output of bin-packing algorithm for weight or volume, using the following assumptions:

1- Each Chromosome represents materials that can be fit in one container.

2- The Chromosome is valid only when it contains valid sum of weights and dimensions.

3- Fitness function would be combination of (occupied space/total space and materials weight/allowed weight).

4- Mutation should be inserting a new item that is not previously used.

My friend did such research as a kind of homework, it might be not that good, but if you wish I can send it to you.